# Stop a script in Matlab

Tags: matlab

My question is, how do I stop a script by a pressing a GUI button? I already tried to write a code that simulates "CTRL+C" press, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry -- why don't you just hit Ctrl-C? Why are you trying to simulate it?

Comment: i just want a user to be able to stop the script that he started by pressing a button on a IDE. Woudl be nice to have a Cancel button.

Comment: I've adjust my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a way to stop another script from being called. One alternative would be to set a global variable that's periodically checked by the script you wish to stop. If you set the value of a "stop processing" variable to true in your callback, the other script could stop if it found that it was supposed to stop.

**Edit**

If you'd like to have a GUI option to stop an ongoing process, I would recommend you take a look at something like [STOPLOOP](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20455) on the MATLAB File Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I won't write the code for you but here's a high-level way to accomplish this:

Display a `waitbar` with a button on it. Create a callback function for the button which sets a flag to true.

Begin computation inside of a for-loop. In the loop:
1. update the waitbar. 
2. call the `drawnow` function so that the callback is executed properly. Remember MATLAB is single-threaded, so this is necessary or the callback will not execute until the script finishes.
3. perform any other computation
4. check for the flag set to true. if it is true, return to stop execution.

The flag could be a global variable, or a handle-based object (so that it is passed by reference).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: 

This answer is not applicable for the current question.

This answer is applicable only for scripts having the first line = `#!/usr/bin/matlab`**

use `pkill` without option will send a TERM signal:

```
pkill yourscriptname
```

If you really want the same signal as `CTRL+C` then:

```
pkill -3 yourscriptname
```

If your script still does not stop, you can use the most aggressive signal KILL:

```
pkill -9 yourscriptname
```

Of course, if you known the `PID` (Process IDentifier), you can simply use `kill`:

```
kill    yourPID
kill -3 yourPID 
kill -9 yourPID
```

You can have more info about **signals** using one of these commands:

```
man 7 signal
kill -l
info signal
```

Comment: Isn't this assuming the OP is using some Unix-based OS?

Comment: That will kill Matlab, instead of stopping the script

Comment: Yep @aardvarkk you are right. When I read `CTRL+C`, I thought about terminal, so Unix-based OS... Maybe I am wrong...

Comment: Maybe i didn't make it enough clear, but i need to write the code inside a MATLAB callback not into a Shell script :D, and what i wanna stop is another MATLAB script.

Comment: Ctrl-C is a command within MATLAB to stop a script that's gone haywire, so I think the OP is looking for something to work within the MATLAB environment. I'm just confused about why they can't just hit Ctrl-C!

Comment: Hi @Andrey. You may have right. I was thinking Daniele Kerberos uses matlab scripts as gnuplot scripts. Thanks for your comment, I edit my answer ;-)

Comment: Sorry @aardvarkk. So I have misunderstood the usage of MATLAB (so much time I haven't wrote any MATLAB script). My apologies.

Comment: @oHessling Don't worry about it! We're all just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do a lot of GUIs, but for debugging purposes I would try to set the button callback to `@keyboard`.  That is, something like:

```
set(handleToGuiButton,'Callback',@keyboard)
```

To actually stop execution you would need to somehow communicate this button press into the loop that was executing, for example via global variables, or something fancier (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8537460/931379)

But I would honestly look at the `stoploop` link (from another answer) before going down any of these routes.