# Mablab calling one figure from another figure

Tags: user-interface, matlab

There are two figures, assume figure 1 and figure 2. In figure 1,there is a button 'Next'. When 'Next' is clicked , figure 2 is expected to appear, this works fine by using the line of code  open('TrafficSignConfig.fig');.

But when i click on exit button in figure 2, this button throws an error message.

'??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in ==> report_search>exit_Callback at 289
delete(handles.figure1);

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ==> report_search at 42
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in ==> @(hObject,eventdata)report_search('exit_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)) '

Can any one please help me on this. i tried to search, but i could get any answers that i understand. Please suggest me an easy method

Comment: What do you mean by "assess the button"?

Comment: First recommendation I have is to post your m/fig files that you use for this project.

Comment: This question may be related, with a little difference in the details:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8531286/931379

Comment: I have  modified my question for better understanding. Please have a look at it. i do not have sufficient reputation to post sample image to help my question.

Comment: `handles.figure1` figure1 is not a member of the `handles` variable is what it appears.

Comment: Can u pls tel me idea on, how to pass 'handles.figure1' of the 2nd figure GUI to 1st figure GUI..  please help me with possible solutions to call 1 GUI window,while giving ability to access controls in 2nd window, from another window in Matlab.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer, it works fine.

Please refer the link below if needed,

http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2005/10/03/guide-video-part-two/