# Using varargin when passing argument into a function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a function called viewcsi(varargin) and I want to pass in three variables at most.
The first is a MBSspectrum class I made and then a string and also a number.

viewcsi is a call back, it gets called like this:

```
...'ButtonDownFcn','viewcsi(''pickvox_cb'', sp_viewcsi)');
```

sp_viewcsi is the MBSspectrum class I made and is in the workspace. I want to be able to add another argument called counter which is integer of type double.

I want to do something like this:

```
...'ButtonDownFcn','viewcsi(''pickvox_cb'', sp_viewcsi, counter)');
```

or

```
...'ButtonDownFcn', {@viewcsi, 'pickvox_cb', 'sp_viewcsi', counter)');
```

But when I do the last two thing these do not work since they do not preserve 'sp_viewcsi' as a class but treats it like a string. What can I do to fix this? I have a feeling its something easy but I havent been able to figure it out.

Comment: Without seeing more code, or better yet a minimal example, it's hard to say, but [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531286/passing-actual-values-to-callback-function-in-matlab) might help.

Comment: Yes more source code is needed but I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ButtonDownFcn` will only ever pass it two arguments. You can cheat it by saying

```
...'ButtonDownFcn',@(a,b)viewcsi(a,b, counter));
```

so that the callback will pass it `a` and `b`, while Matlab will hand it the current value of `counter`.

See also the doc on [passing extra parameters](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html).