# How to create an 'closure function' in Matlab as in python and js?

Tags: matlab, function, closures

### Background

In Python and JS we have closures, which returns a function with some of the variables pre-defined. e.g.

```
def make_printer(msg):
    def printer():
        print msg
    return printer
```

### Do we have similar stuff in Matlab?

Here I have a callback function

```
function show(object, eventdata)
```

that is to be set to the callback of my GUI

```
func = @show;
set(gcf, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', func);
```

However, I want to add some additional parameters to this `show` function.

Currently I'm using global variables to do that. But I think it would be elegant if we have a 'closures function'.

### About anonymous function

Yes we do have anonymous function in Matlab. However it seems to me that it is too simple to support 60-line procedures.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your question, but in case this helps before someone more knowledgable comes along, I'll make a suggestion. You can add an additional argument to a callback function, `function callbackFunction(object,eventdata,variable)`. You may be able to add multiple extra arguments I haven't tried, I make a struct with all of the variables used by my GUI and just use it as the third input argument. Hope that is relevant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like my comment was helpful, I'll explain what I mean about the struct thing. I think the way you are calling the callback functions is slightly different, so this may not work so well).

If you have a bunch of different callback functions, and a bunch of variables you want to pass to them, it is annoying and difficult to have a big list of input arguments for each function. Instead, I do something like this:

First create a bunch of UI components , but don't specify their callback functions, e.g

```
radio1_handle=uicontrol(panel1_handle,'Style','radiobutton',...
    'Min',0,'Max',1,'Value',0,'Units','normalized','Position',[.8 .8 .2 .25]);
```

once you have made all the components, create a struct of variables you will be using

```
vars=struct('varName1',var1,'varName2',var2);
```

then update the UI components to include the callback functions

```
set(radio1_handle,'Callback',{@radio1_callback,vars});
```

now create the actual functions

```
function radio1_callback(object,eventData,vars)
```

So it's nothing fancy, just a potentially neater way than using multiple arguments.

Answer (score 2):

There was once a document floating about the internet by Sergey Simakov. It was very terse , not especially descriptive but covered the bases. This was in my experience the most authoritive text on matlab GUI's. I suspect it still is ...

You're solving two/three problems :

**Closure Problem**

Nested functions resolve this problem.

```
function iterator = count(initial)
 % Initialize
 if ~exist('initial','var')
  counter = 0
 else
  counter = initial
 end
 function varargout = next() % [1] 
  % Increment
  counter = counter + 1
  varargout = {counter}      % [1] 
 end
 iterator = @next
end
```

Note(s) :

1. One may not simply return counter ! It must be wrapped in varargout or assigned to some other output variable.

Usage

```
counter = count(4) % Instantiate
number = counter() % Assignment
number = 
  5
```

---

**Closed Scope + State problem**

No ugly braces, worrying about scope, cell arrays of strings. If you need access to something it's under SELF no more FINDOBJ, USERDATA, SET/GETAPPDATA, GLOBAL nonsense.

```
classdef Figure < handle

 properties 
  parent@double
  button@double
  label@double
  counter@function_handle
 end

 methods 
  function self = Figure(initial)
   self.counter = count(initial) % [1]
   self.parent  = figure('Position',[200,200,300,100])
   self.button  = uicontrol('String','Push',          'Callback', @self.up, 'Style', 'pushbutton', 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0.05, 0.05, 0.9, 0.4])
   self.label   = uicontrol('String', self.counter(),                       'Style', 'text',       'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0.05, 0.55, 0.9, 0.4])
  end

  function up(self,comp,data)
   set(self.label,'String',self.counter())
  end
 end
end
```

Note(s):

1. One uses the function listed in the Closure problem above

Usage :

```
f = Figure(4)                  % Instantiate
number = get(f.label,'String') % Assign
number = 
  5
```

You may prefer :

```
f.label.get('String')          % Fails (f.label is double not handle, go figure)
h = handle(f.label)            % Convert Double to handle
number = h.get('String')       % Works 
number = 
  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531286/passing-actual-values-to-callback-function-in-matlab) and @David's comment, I came up with the solution. (Maybe this is @David's answer, but not explicitly explained. So let me extend his comment into an answer.)

There is actually a way to add extra parameters to callbacks.

Just add the parameters to the end of the parameter list

```
function show(object, eventdata, extra)
```

and set the callback like this:

```
func = @show;
```

set(gcf, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', func);

### Reference

[Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.cn/cn/help/matlab/creating_plots/function-handle-callbacks.html)

> Passing Additional Input Arguments
>
> You can define the callback function to accept additional input
>   arguments by adding them to the function definition:
>
> ```
> function myCallback(src,eventdata,arg1,arg2)
> ```
>
> When using additional
>   arguments for the callback function, you must set the value of the
>   property to a cell array (i.e., enclose the function handle and
>   arguments in curly braces):
>
> ```
> figure('WindowButtonDownFcn',{@myCallback,arg1,arg2})
> ```

Comment: Cool. I added an answer explaining what I meant, but I think you have the complete solution here.

Comment: Pretty much the same. Actually the callback can get several extra parameters, so no bother the struct. Am I right on this?

Comment: Yep. The only reason to use a struct is that if you change the code you don't have to update a whole bunch of variables in a whole bunch of functions. I was working with about 15 variables in each of about 10 callback functions, and putting them in a struct just made it easier to manage.